# catplot(kind="count") is significantly slower than countplot()

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I am working on a fairly large dataset (~40m rows). I have found that if I call **sns.countplot()** directly then my visualisation plots really quickly:

```
%%time 
ax = sns.countplot(x="age_band",data=acme)
```

[image: Plot using axis level function directly:]

However if I do the same visualisation using **catplot(kind="count")** then the speed of execution slows down dramatically:

```
%%time
g = sns.catplot(x="age_band",data=acme,kind="count")
```

[image: # Plot using figure level function with kind="count"]

Is there a reason for such a large performance difference? Is **catplot()** doing some sort of conversion on my data before it can plot it?

If there is a known reason for this, then does it extend to all figure level functions vs axis level functions eg is **sns.scatterplot()** faster that **sns.relplot(kind="scatter")** etc?

My preference would be to use **catplot()** as I like its flexibility and easy  plotting on a FacetGrid but if it is going to take so much longer to achieve the same plot then I will just use the axis level functions directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of overhead in `catplot`, or for that matter in `FacetGrid`, that will ensure that the categories are synchronized along the grid. Consider e.g. that you have a variable you plot along the columns of the grid for which not every age group occurs. You would still need to show that non-occuring age group and hold on to its color. Hence, two countplots next to each other do not necessarily make up one catplot.

However, if you are only interested in a single countplot, a catplot is clearly overkill. On the other hand, even a single countplot is overkill compared to a barplot of the counts. That is,

```
counts = df["Category"].value_counts().sort_index()
colors = plt.cm.tab10(np.arange(len(counts)))
ax = counts.plot.bar(color=colors)
```

will be twice as fast as

```
ax = sns.countplot(x="Category", data=df)
```