# difference between countplot and catplot

Tags: python

In python seaborn, What is the difference between `countplot` and `catplot`?

Eg:

```
sns.catplot(x='class', y='survived', hue='sex', kind='bar', data=titanic);
```

```
sns.countplot(y='deck', hue='class', data=titanic);
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [catplot(kind="count") is significantly slower than countplot()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57990852/catplotkind-count-is-significantly-slower-than-countplot)

Answer (score 2):

[`seaborn.countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html#seaborn-countplot)

> Shows the counts of observations in each categorical bin using bars.

[`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html#seaborn-catplot)

> Provides access to several axes-level functions that show the relationship between a numerical and one or more categorical variables using one of several visual representations.

Answer (score 2):

There is a lot of overhead in catplot, or for that matter in FacetGrid, that will ensure that the categories are synchronized along the grid. Consider e.g. that you have a variable you plot along the columns of the grid for which not every age group occurs. You would still need to show that non-occuring age group and hold on to its color. Hence, two countplots next to each other do not necessarily make up one catplot.

However, if you are only interested in a single countplot, a catplot is clearly overkill. On the other hand, even a single countplot is overkill compared to a barplot of the counts.